# Manage UI Tests with each branch

Tags: continuous-integration, development-process, uiautomation

Well, we are currently working on three branches: dev, staging, and master

My UI tests are running on continued integration pointing only to the dev branch and to the dev application as well. The other branches are ignored just because all tests point only to the development application (eg dev.minhaapp.com).

Doubts:

How are you managing currently branches x UITests?
Does each branch point to a specific URL to run the tests?

Answer (score 1):

I am managing this scenario as follows:

1. Created jobs for each branch in CI.
2. Scheduled the jobs.
3. Configured the jobs to run in the respective server.

Note:
My UI tests are having config.properties file to fetch the url.
Yes. Each branch will point to the specific urls.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options here:

- Develop the tests and configure your CI framewrok in the way they pick the settings from environment properties. So that you can configure each run to deploy the app to URL you want and from the branch you want and hence to target your tests to that app.
- Configure a single point for every build (e.g. test.minhaapp.com). In such the configuration your tests will target that single point, but the CI framewrok will have to undeploy the app buit from one branch and deploy the app built from another one.